# is there any way to use xml comment on methods for swagger but without generating xml file?

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, xml-comments

i have a project and im using this configuration for swagger and swagger documention

```
        public static void AddSwagger(this IServiceCollection services, string AssemblyName)
        {
            string releaseType = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            if (releaseType != "Production")
            {
                services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                    {
                        //info
                    });

                    var xmlFile = $"{AssemblyName}.xml";
                    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
                });

            }
        }
```

and this is how i comment on my methodes

```
        // GET: api/Article/ShowThumbnail/5
        /// <summary>Shows the thumbnail.</summary>
        /// <param name="id">The identifier.</param>
        /// <param name="width">The width.</param>
        /// <returns>
        ///   <br />
        /// </returns>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("[action]/{id:int}/{width:int?}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ShowThumbnail(int id, int width = 100)
        {
            return await base.ShowThumbnail(id, width, ContentTypeEnum.Article);
        }
```

is there a way to use this type of comments without generating xml file?
i want to delete this part of my SwaggerExtension

```
                    var xmlFile = $"{AssemblyName}.xml";
                    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
```

i remove xmlfilegenerator in csprojects and i dont want any warning in project

Comment: What's the problem of having this xml file generated?

Comment: @SteveB I don't know there is some problem with DevOps and this file I just have to delete it

Comment: maybe you should try to fix the actual issue in your devops platform, instead of trying to hack some standard behavior

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.